# Eloquent::where() condition is not working as expected, but Collection::where() does work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I've been playing around with Eloquent for a while, but I met a case where Eloquent::where() is not working as I expected. I managed to get Collection::where() worked instead though. However, I'm still wondering why Eloquent::where() didn't work in my case. I will keep the problem as simple as I can, here it goes:

- I have Product and ProductCategory as many-to-many relationships and the pivot table name is "product_relate_category".
- Here is the relationship between them. It's still working so you can skip

---

```
Models/Product {
    public function productCategory() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategory::class, 'product_relate_category','product_id','category_id');
    }
}
Models/ProductCategory {
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_relate_category', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

---

- Here is the tricky part: We need to display related products, which are in the same product category but have a different ID. Let's take the first product, for example, the task is to get all relating products

  > ```
  > foreach (Product::first()->productCategory()->get() as $category)
  > {
  >     foreach($category->product()->where("id", "<>", Product::first()->id)->get() as $result)
  >     {
  >          echo($result->name); 
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
- Seems like working? No, it says: "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous".
- Now if I omit the `Eloquent::where()` condition above, I have access to all Products with their "id" present, which is a big confusion.
- But, if I change it to either of the below, it works perfectly

  ```
   $category->product()->where("product_id", "<>", Product::first()->id)->get()
  ```

  //Notice "id" has changed to "product_id"

OR

```
    $category->product()->get()->where("id", "<>", Product::first()->id) 
//Method order changed
```

- With the second instance, Collection::where() has been called, which I quite reluctant to use. So is there any explanation for this case and why Eloquent behaves in this way?

Comment: actually dont need that much logic i  guess.you can do this Product::with('productCategory')->get();

Comment: This might indicate that the pivot `product_relate_category` incorrectly has an id field on it

Comment: @JohnLobo It does shorten the process. However not really what I'm wondering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your where in the query, you have used the column 'id' which is existed in the product_relate_category table and products table, so the database can't determine exactly what column you mean ...
in this case you should write the full column name:

```
 $category->product()->where("products.id", "<>", Product::first()->id)->get();
```

Comment: It definitely the problem. Is there any document on that syntax?
I thought when ->product() is used, Eloquent automatically assumes "id" column in the products table, it doesn't?